# Why does my ImageView work on Windows but not on Mac

Tags: java, windows, macos, javafx

Here is the simple code for javafx in intellij:

```
Image image = new Image(url);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
movieBox.getChildren().add(imageView);

//checking
System.out.println(imageView.getImage().getUrl());
Textfield tx = new Textfield();
tx.setText("hi");
movieBox.getChildren().add(tx);
```

I copied the project over to intellij on my mac and everything works accept the images won't show. Here are the things I tried:

- Checking that the URL is valid by printing out the imageview image url. It prints out a valid URL of an image i can open in my browswer
- Adding a random textfield to the movieBox (a flowpane object) to make sure it works. And it does.

There shouldn't be any error in the code because it works in my windows intellij. It seems like a problem with the environment, but I haven't even got a clue how should i approach this problem. Any sort of advice will be nice, thanks!

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the image and using the path to the image on your disk, if it works then the problem will be with the url, otherwise its with the ImageView. If the problem is with the URL, post the one you are trying to use so the community can test it, and try another URL.

P.S. If you aren't manipulating the image you can just pass the path/url directly top the ImageView constructor.

> public ImageView(String url) 
>   Allocates a new ImageView object with image loaded from the specified URL.
>   The new ImageView(url) has the same effect as new ImageView(new Image(url)).